# Can't make button react to onClick

Tags: android, android-layout, onclick, android-xml

I have these 2 buttons inside an Activity. The `backBtn` works fine, but nothing happens when I click on the `reg_country` button. Any idea of what's going on?

[EDIT] Edited with some log, `onClick` just does't executes when I touch the button.

```
 08-10 09:33:08.608: D/dalvikvm(806): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 365 objects / 24360 bytes in 58ms
 08-10 09:33:11.608: E/RegisterActivity(806): Activity started
 08-10 09:33:14.317: E/RegisterActivity(806): onClick (backBtn)
 08-10 09:33:16.268: E/RegisterActivity(806): Activity started
```

Part of the Activity code

```
Log.e("RegisterActivity", "Activity started");

backBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backBtn);
backBtn.setText("Cancelar");
backBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

backBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.e("RegisterActivity", "onClick (backBtn)");
        finish();
    }
});


reg_country = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reg_country);
reg_country.setText("reg_country");
reg_country.setClickable(true);
reg_country.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.e("RegisterActivity", "onClick (reg_country)");
        finish();
    }
});
```

Maybe because `reg_country` stays inside a `TableLayout`? backBtn comes from the included `actionbar_layout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include1"
        layout="@layout/actionbar_layout" />

    <!-- Registration Form -->

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:background="@drawable/balao_formulario_cadastrar"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:paddingTop="50dip"
        android:stretchColumns="1" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/reg_fullname"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:background="@drawable/stroke"
            android:hint="Nome Completo"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/reg_email"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:background="@drawable/stroke"
            android:hint="E-mail"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/reg_password"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:background="@drawable/stroke"
            android:hint="Senha"
            android:password="true"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/reg_country"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dip"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:text="Selecione um País"
            android:textSize="15dip" />

        <!-- Terms of Use TextView -->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/reg_terms_link"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/termos"
            android:textColor="#3D3D3D"
            android:textSize="10dip" />
    </TableLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/registerBtn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:background="@drawable/button_cadastrar"
        android:text="Cadastrar"
        android:textColor="#3D3D3D"
        android:textSize="15dip" />

    <!-- Registration Form Ends -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I am not sure that finish inside the listener calls finish of the activity. you should check that.

Comment: Well backBtn is finishing the activity correctly...

Comment: Does `reg_country.setText("reg_country");` work?

Comment: maybe some log could clear the issue? could you post it from your logcat?

Comment: yes, setText does changes the button label...

Comment: Thats weird. For me it works. Have you tried some Log Messages for the LogCat? By the way I dont see your Back-Button in the XML. May be a long shot but is there something missing?

Comment: Both worked perfectly in my app, please check the `XML`

Comment: Are you sure that the event is triggered in both case?

Comment: The backBtn comes from the included actionbar_layout, jus above the TableLayout.Running my code step by step, the onclick of reg_country doesn't executes...

Comment: I`ve declared testMethod() on my activity and used android:onClick="testMehtod()" at the button attributes. Now I'm getting an exception "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method testMethod()(View) in the activity class"

Comment: Just changed testMethod() to testMethod(View v) and now it works! :D